# How to read reference $ref of JSON file?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{
  "description": "Something",
  "id": "abc.def.xyzjson#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "triggerTime": {
      "description": "Something",
      "$ref": "abc.def.xyz.1.json#"
      "required": true
    },
    "customerId": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Something",
      "$ref": "abc.def.xyz.1.json#"
    },
```

..... many more keys........
I need to go into the $ref file location and lode that json into a map 
Please help me out how to read.
Already I am able to read the main file like

```
File jsonInputFile = new File("location");
System.out.println("Keys : " + entry2.getKey());
```

Comment: you can use gson, check the following link https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: What is `entry2`?

Comment: All json parsing is the same. Start  from the top. Know what's an object and an array. You can have no arrays here, so should be easy to get the customerId, and it's inner  ref

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for getting the $ref value

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "File location"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject properties = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("properties");
            JSONObject triggerTime = (JSONObject) properties.get("triggerTime");
            String ref = (String) triggerTime.get("$ref");//You can load this file to a map if required.
            System.out.println(ref);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output is

> abc.def.xyz.1.json#